# HTML image resize

Tags: html, image, visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4c4kN.png) I'm very new to this, I can't seem to figure out why cant I drag an image to my image folder and also I don't know how to resize my image to fit my website, can someone please help me? I am using vs code [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNaOl.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZPuw.jpg)

I checked on to find available fixes and on mdn however I am confused

Comment: Please post your code as code, as text, not as an image. What do you mean you "can't drag an image to your image folder"? What confuses you on MDN? At the minute this reads like a question on how to use your computer, and possibly read/write permissions, which isn't a coding problem. You may - depending on the clarity and explanations you can offer in the question - be better off asking over on [SU], but do read their help pages first. However, [edit] your question *here* to try to share your code properly, and explain the problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can't drag your image inside your images folder because it's not a folder, for create a folder it's second icon of the left of "Web D..." (the folder where you put HTML - Personal Site) or you can also create it manually in your file manager

For resize your image you can use the style inside your image balise

`<img src="" style="height: 100px; width: 100px">`

Answer (score 0):

*images* is not a folder. It's a text file. To create a folder click on the second icon on the left from the name of the current folder (Web D...) - Your HTML - Personal Site folder is inside that folder. Then you will be able to drag it inside. You can also create new folder manually directly from you file manager/explorer.

You can resize your image directly in HTML by adding *width* and *height* inside *style* attribute:

```html
<img src="Steven.png" style="width: 250px; height: 95px;"
```

Or you can do the same inside CSS:

```css
img {
   width: 250px;
   height: 95px;
}
```